# sending file via WhatsApp from Windows application C#

Tags: c#, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want send a pdf file from c# windows application via WhatsApp. How can I do that?
I khow its possible sending text messages by wa link but for attaching file like pdf I can't find anyway.

Comment: I think you're looking for WA API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Because this question is too broad in terms of correct answer, I will post a few links, which might help you do what you asked ( depending on your needs ) :

1. https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-twilio-api-whatsapp
2. https://whatsmate.github.io/2018-01-17-send-whatsapp-pdf-c-sharp-dot-net/
3. https://whatsmate.github.io/2018-01-23-send-whatsapp-pdf-group-c-sharp-dot-net/
4. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media

Comment: Thanks alot. I check those and all of that aren't free. Is there any free way? And other problem i think whatsapp api doesn't support  some of countries.

Comment: You are welcome. As far as Twillio , I can see that there is a list of blocked countries : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051177134-What-countries-can-I-reach-with-the-Twilio-API-for-WhatsApp-  . I am not sure for whatsmate though , but I suppose contacting their support would get you more information about blocked countries. Of course you can download the Business Api directly from Whatsapp's website, but of course you would need to go through the registration process : https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api . I haven't heard of any free solution so far.

Comment: Thanks for your answer